# scilab : index in variable name loop

Tags: variables, image-processing, for-loop, scilab

i would like to read some images with scilab and i use the function imread like this

```
im01=imread('kodim01t.jpg');
im02=imread('kodim02t.jpg');
im03=imread('kodim03t.jpg');
im04=imread('kodim04t.jpg');
im05=imread('kodim05t.jpg');
im06=imread('kodim06t.jpg');
im07=imread('kodim07t.jpg');
im08=imread('kodim08t.jpg');
im09=imread('kodim09t.jpg');
im10=imread('kodim10t.jpg');
```

i would like to know if there is a way to do something like below in order to optimize the

```
for i = 1:5  
    im&i=imread('kodim0&i.jpg');
end
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions using [execstr](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/execstr.html) or using some kind of list/matrix

### Execstr

First create a string of the command to execute with [msprintf](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/msprintf.html) and then execute this with [execstr](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/execstr.html). Note that in the [msprintf](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/msprintf.html) conversion the right amount of leading zeros are inserted by `%0d` format specifier descbribed [here](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/printf_conversion.html).

```
for i = 1:5  
    cmd=msprintf('im%d=imread(\'kodim%02d.jpg\');', i, i);
    execstr(cmd);
end
```

### List/Matrix

This is probably the more intuitive option using a indexable container such as [list](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/list.html).

```
// This list could be generated using msprintf from example above
file_names_list = list("kodim01t.jpg", "kodim02t.jpg" ,"kodim03t.jpg");

// Create empty list to contain images
opened_images = list();

for i=1:length(file_names_list)

    // Open image and insert it at end of list
    opened_images($+1) = imread(file_names_list[i]);
end
```